# Powershell Function Variables

Tags: function, variables, powershell

I'm writing a script to find local admins on machines in a specific OU.  I've created two functions to preform this task, each function by itself is working fine, but when I combine the two I am not getting any result.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    Function GetCompList{
Get-ADObject -Filter { ObjectClass -eq "computer" } -SearchBase "OU=Resources,DC=Contoso,DC=LOCAL" `
| Select-Object Name
}

Function Admin_Groups{
foreach($i in GetCompList){
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$i"
$Object = $adsi.Children | ? {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | % {
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        UserName = $_.Name -join ''
        Groups = ($_.Groups()  |Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}) -join ',' 
    }    
} 
$Object |? {$_.Groups -match "Administrators*"}

}
}

Admin_Groups
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetCompList` function is returning a collection of objects. You're probably getting this when you run the one function:

```
Name
------
Comp1
Comp2
Comp3
```

In the `foreach` loop of `Admin_Groups`, you're using the output of `GetCompList` as an array of primitives - just a list of names, not a bunch of objects. So, you have two options:

1. Change the `select-object name` in `GetCompList` to `select-object -expandproperty Name` to get a simple array of names
2. In `Admin_Groups`, change each reference to `$i` in the body of the `foreach` loop to `$i.Name`. Since you're using it within a string, it's a little ugly to do that.

In this particular example, my preference would be option #1, making that function:

```
Function GetCompList{
    Get-ADObject -Filter { ObjectClass -eq "computer" } -SearchBase "OU=Resources,DC=Contoso,DC=LOCAL" | Select-Object -expandproperty Name
}
```

I would also suggest that you rename your functions to match the Verb-Noun convention of PowerShell, and use one of the approved verbs from `get-verb`.

```
Get-CompList
Get-AdminGroups
```

Failing that, at least make your function names consistent - either use the `_` to separate the words in the names, or don't. Don't mix & match.